# Different MSE for each observation for SARIMA-model

Tags: time-series, arima, mse

I am doing a time series forecast with the SARIMA-model in STATA. I wanted to calculate the MSE to set up confidence intervals for my prediction. I have done that using the following command:

predict MSE, mse dynamic(tm(2022m5))

STATA then generates a new variable of course with the MSE in it. Now I am wondering why the MSE is not similar for each observation. It is about roughly the same value for all observations of one year with some exceptions. It heavily differs for different years though.

For me (if i have not fundamentally misunderstood the concept of MSE) it just does not make sense to have different values for the MSE for each observation.

I would apreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

The concept of MSE:

MSE measures the amount of error in statistical models. It assesses the average squared difference between the observed and predicted values.

MSE = SUM(square(Real_Y(i'th) - Predicted_Y(i'th)))/(the-number-of-observations)

Since STATA generates new random variables you have to use set seed to initialize a pseudorandom generator

this article will help you to understand set seed
https://www.stata.com/manuals13/rsetseed.pdf